# C++ Pi Approximation using Leibniz Formula

Tags: c++, for-loop, approximation

I'm a beginner at C++ and coding itself, so please forgive any vocabulary mishaps. I couldn't find this specific question but similar ones on the internet, but I'm still having a hard time getting an outcome I need.

So I'm using the Leibniz Formula to approximate pi which is:

pi = 4 · [ 1 – 1/3 + 1/5 – 1/7 + 1/9 … + (–1 ^ n)/(2n + 1) ].

I've written a [compilable and runnable program](https://ideone.com/en2U9d) , but the main part of the code that's troubling me is:

```
if (terms > 0){

        double partial = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < terms; i++)
            if (i % 2 == 0)
                partial -= (pow(-1,terms))/((2.0 * i) + 1);
            else
                partial += (pow(-1,terms))/((2.0 * i) + 1);

        double newPi = 4 * partial;

        cout << "The approximation is " << newPi << " using " << terms << " terms.\n";

}
```

If terms = 3, the approximation = 2.895

If terms = 10, the approximation = 3.232

If terms = 50, the approximation = 3.161

I'm not getting any of these numbers. I've noticed though, that when I put in an odd number, I get a negative and vice versa with even numbers. Everything I have written in my program is everything I have learned in my class so far, so I cannot really go out of the scope I've written in. Any help or explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an if/else to determine the sign, but then you also do `pow(-1, terms)`. I would just get rid of the `pow` and replace it with `1`, since you are already doing `partial +=` and `partial -=` depending if `i` is odd or even. Also, I think your `+=` and `-=` should be the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (terms > 0){
     double partial = 0;
     for (i = 0; i <= terms; i++)
         partial += pow(-1,i)/(2.0 * i + 1);
     double newPi = 4 * partial;
     cout << "The approximation is " << newPi << " using " << terms << " terms.\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the computing of *pow(-1,i)* at each loop by using a variable holding sign condition between the loops.

```
if (terms > 0){
    double newPi = 0.0;
        for (int i=0; i < n; ++i) { 
            newPi += sign / (2.0 * i + 1.0);
            sign  = -sign; 
        }
        newPi *= 4;
        cout << "The approximation is " << newPi << " using " << terms << " terms.\n";
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).