# having trouble getting correct output from approximation formula in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

double get_Pi(double accuracy)
{
    double Pi_estimate = 0;
    double increment = 0;
    double i = 0;
    int s = -1;


      while(fabs(increment) > accuracy)
     {

            increment = s*(1/(2*i+1));
              Pi_estimate = Pi_estimate + increment;
             s = -s;
             i++;
       }

       double offset = 1.0;
       Pi_estimate = Pi_estimate + offset;
       return 4*Pi_estimate;
       }



 int main()
{
   double accuracy;
     printf("\nhow accurate do you want Pi? ");
       scanf("%lf", &accuracy);
         double approx = get_Pi(accuracy);
       printf("%.10lf", approx);
        return 0;
      }
```

By inputting a certain decimal you should get pi to + or - the precision you inputted but the output is always 4.00000.

Answer (score 1):

You're starting from 0 instead of 1 and adding instead of subtracting in the denominator of your term, you're calculating the new value of `increment` using integer operations instead of floating point, and your `while` loop never gets entered because `increments` starts at 0.

The correct formula is:   pi / 4 = sum(k->inf) ((-1)^(k+1))/(2k-1)

So you would do this as:

```
double get_Pi(double accuracy)
{
    double Pi_estimate = 0;
    double increment;
    double i = 1;    // start at 1
    int s = 1;       // start with positive factor

    do {    // do the check at the bottom instead of the top
        increment = s*(1.0/(2.0*i-1));    // use floating point constants to prevent integer division
        Pi_estimate = Pi_estimate + increment;
        s = -s;
        i++;
    } while(fabs(increment) > accuracy);

    // no need to add an offset
    return 4*Pi_estimate;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This question is very similar to [C++ Pi Approximation using Leibniz Formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39987538/c-pi-approximation-using-leibniz-formula), which I believe is what you're looking for (despite it being a C++ question).

Your while loop never enters, since this condition can't happen unless accuracy is negative (0>accuracy)
so you get result of (Pi_estimate =1)*4 = 4

Comment: thanks for the editing. Please let me know how you keep connect the link to the text, I tried several times and it didn't work for me